# MySQL Foreign Key Lookup in Editor

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I am flummoxed that no one seems to have ever asked this question, which indicates that the question itself is flawed. But, I don't know how to find out the right question, or answer, other than asking, so here goes:

I'm trying out a couple of tools to connect to MySQL databases and view and edit the data. So far I've tried MySQL Workbench and Database Browser. MySQL Workbench seems to be much more robust and lets you set up foreign keys without having to write any SQL.

The problem, though, is that when inserting and updating data in columns that are foreign keys, I have to manually enter the numeric id of the parent row, and once entered, I have to manually look up which record that number refers to if I want to know. Is there no way to set a display field in the parent table and then be able to choose a value off a dropdown menu when editing the child table? phpMyAdmin does this. I'm perplexed that, not only can't I find a way to achieve this in any non-web-based database tool (I've tried Access before, too), but that no one seems ever to have needed to do it before. Am I completely thinking about this wrong? Do people not use these tools to do this type of work? Is everyone writing their own custom lookup interfaces from scratch in Qbasic? Should I memorize all the ids for my parent rows?

Or are people laughing up their sleeves at this question because it's framed so awkwardly?

Comment: I have not seen any serious large scale production system use Workbench, SMSS, Toad, phpAdmin to edit and create data in production. They are generally used to perform admin tasks such as backup and session monitoring. Most of the data editing and inserting goes through scripts which goes through QA and testing before hitting production. As a matter of fact I cant remember a developer in the last 5-8 years using the visual grid editors to insert data manually like that.

Comment: You mean something like this: http://www.sql-workbench.net/fk_lookup_png.html ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, that's a good example! Not exactly the UI I had in mind, but definitely the functionality.

Comment: @Namphibian Yes, I can see that it would be bad to use it for inputting large quantities of production data, but it would be super useful for testing, both for inputting data and also for tracing the structure of existing databases that one didn't develop but is expected to maintain, especially when there is no documentation.

Comment: John I would suggest you acript the inserts for testing. If you need to reset after a test you can just run the scripts much easier than restoring the database for example.

Comment: @Namphibian, how about "reverse-engineering" the complicated structure of a poorly documented database in order to elucidate exactly how it works? Surely there's an easier way than manually chasing down a web of foreign keys. Yes, sub-ideal... but this kind of thing happens in the real world more often than I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

SQLYog provides such functionality
https://blog.webyog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/FK-Dropdown1.png

Comment: Your suggestion seems reasonable. A link to SQLYog itself, rather than just a screenshot, would be helpful here.